# R: creating a new variable in data frame inside a user defined function

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe with (age and gender). Based on the age and gender of each record in my dataframe, I want to look through a reference data frame (called `bmi`)and calculate something and create a new variable in my data frame and assign to the calulated value to it. Following is my function for the calculation `lambda`

```
lambda <-function(ag, gnd, ibmi) {

  sel <- ibmi[ibmi$age==ag & ibmi$gender == gnd, ]
  out <- boxcox(lm(bmi~1, data = sel), data = sel)
  rn <- range(out$x[out$y > max(out$y)-qchisq(0.95,1)/2])
  (rn[1] + rn[2])/2
}
```

This is how I call this function and create the new variable in my data frame

`myData$L <- lambda(myData$age, myData$gender, bmi)`

I pass `age`, `gender` and reference data frame `bmi` to the function `lambda`. But I get the following Warning and getting same answer repeated for all the records of different age and gender.

```
Warning messages:
1: In ibmi$age == ag :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In ibmi$gender == gnd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: `myData` and result of `lambda` function obviously differ in number of rows/length. `lambda` function results in two numbers (this is what `range` returns), not `nrow(myData)`. If you provide a reproducible example and what the desired output should look like maybe I can help.

Comment: I think you need to loop over each row of your data.frame, with something like `plyr::adply(mydata, 1, function(x) lambda(x$age, x$gender, bmi))`